# Auto type property in combo box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box in my winform. I have some items in it. I want to run the autocompelete true and fill from listitems. I am getting this property worked but i want that all the list items should be present in the combo and the whatever i type should remain at the top.

Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: have you try this with textbox and listbox ? .. and do it textbox's keypress event then hilite value in listbox by findstring methode ..

Comment: i am trying this with listbox,

Answer (score 0):

to add the listbox item to the combobox you could use:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange((From item In ListBox1.Items Select item).ToArray)
```

Comment: Thanks suggestions. But actually what I want is that while autocompelete is on I should be able to view all other items in list while typing. Like if i type S auto type property will take cursor to all elements with s but other items should also be present